# matching impedance and maximize the speaker’s output

Tags: impedance-matching

If I have a signal generator with 600 ohm output resistance and a 8 ohm speaker.
The number of turns in primary coil is 50, so the turn ratio should be
$$\frac{600}{8}=(\frac{N_2}{50})^2 \\N_2=433\\N_1:N_2=50:433$$
Furthermore, will there be any difference on maximizing the power output with applying different frequency output in the signal generator!? such as 1khz vs 5khz.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've got it backwards.  You have a 600 Ω signal and want to drive a 8 Ω load.  Apparently you are trying to do this with a transformer between the two.  Clearly the primary needs to have the higher number of turns.

Your resistance ratio is (600 Ω)/(8 Ω) = 75.  The turns ratio needs to be the square root of that, which is 8.66.  (50 turns)/8.66 = 5.8 turns.  That's what the secondary should be.